# Assigning particular value in a new column for particular name from another column

Tags: python, pandas

```
def construct(x):
  for i in x:
    if i=="Orion":
      return 0.131
    elif i=="Omega":
      return 0.148
    elif i=="Oyster":
      return 0.106
    elif i=="Skyraa":
      return 0

merged_df['Tower construct %']=construct(merged_df['Tower'])
```

Based on the above function I want to map the particular numbers in a new column against the names from a different column, however in the new column I am only getting the figure 0.131, what is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that your function return after the first step and the first value is broadcasted to the full column.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: Remove the for-loop from the function and use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map):

```py
def construct(val):
    if val == "Orion":
        return 0.131
    elif val == "Omega":
        return 0.148
    elif val == "Oyster":
        return 0.106
    elif val == "Skyraa":
        return 0


merged_df["Tower construct %"] = merged_df["Tower"].map(construct)
print(merged_df)
```

Prints:

```
    Tower  Tower construct %
0   Orion              0.131
1   Omega              0.148
2  Oyster              0.106
3  Skyraa              0.000
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can you please tell me what was the issue when I was using the loop function

Comment: @NishantPadhee You're returning from the function in first iteration.